# onItemClickListener into GridView don't catch click events when displayed WebView components

Tags: android, gridview, webview, onitemclicklistener

I need to displayed WebView components into GridView. The problem is that on android 2.3.x the onItemClickListener don't catch the click events.  It's ok on android 2.2.x . The problem for me depend by webview function isInTouchMode() that return always TRUE on android 2.3 and return false on android 2.2. I think that the solution is set to false this parameter, but i don't know how!! 
There is anyone that can help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have using following code:

```
public class GifView extends WebView {

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setClickable(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        setLongClickable(false);

    }

    // actions

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I've created MyWebView object that extends WebView and that overrides some methods:

```
    @Override
public boolean isInTouchMode() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i have followed u r steps but still not solve my problem . Am working in 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Jason Shah explains everything in [this post](http://quitenoteworthy.blogspot.com/2010/12/handling-android-23-webviews-broken.html):

> Handling Android 2.3 WebView's broken AddJavascriptInterface
>
> (Apologies in advance to my normal readers for this technical topic.)
>
> The Google Android team released the Android 2.3 ("Gingerbread") SDK
>   two days ago, to much fanfare. This has sent the tech blogging world
>   into a publishing frenzy, as it usually does. However, a potentially
>   disastrous bug has surfaced that could crash literally thousands of
>   apps in the Android Market immediately after opening the app.
>
> The problem is described succintly here:
>   http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987 In short: Many
>   apps show all or part of their UI with embedded WebViews that can
>   render HTML. Those WebViews make use of a great feature that bridges
>   JavaScript (in the HTML) to the native Java code that "surrounds" the
>   WebView. This bridge is completely broken in Android 2.3. Trying to
>   make even a basic call breaks the WebView immediately and crashes the
>   app.
>
> I believe members of the Android team are aware of the problem, and
>   from early reports, it does not affect the Nexus S (the first Android
>   2.3 phone). This doesn't really help those of us working against the emulator, however.